# How to get exact phrase match out of Graph API search

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api

Looking for a way to get an exact phrase match out of the Graph API's search endpoint.  For example, all activities with "dogs and cats" in them. Putting the phrase in quotes doesn't seem to work, the API will return activities containing those words, but in any order.

```
curl -v "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22dogs%20and%20cats%22&type=post&limit=75&access_token=&since=Wed+Jan+25+20%3A59%3A30&until=Wed+Jan+25+20%3A59%3A40"
```

returns and activity whose text is:

> "Ohhh man it's raining dogs cats lobsters crab birds and horses up here. I'm scared!"

"dogs" "cats" and "and" are all in that post, but not in order.

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing the same issue. Tried quotes, escaping, you name it.. While at the same note - any luck with 'or' and 'and' expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I faced the same problem. There's a similar question that might help [Using the Facebook Graph API to search for an exact string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547023/using-the-facebook-graph-api-to-search-for-an-exact-string?rq=1)

Facebook doesnt allow exact phrasal matching drectly, atleast not at the API level, You would have to fetch the entire data and programmically check for exact matches (too slow though).