# Using the Facebook Graph API to search for an exact string

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to use the Facebook Graph API to search for exact page matches to "My String".

I tried https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22My%20String%22&type=page - but it returns pages that match either "String" or "My".

How do I construct a search query that returns only exact matches to the quoted string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you can't. It's triaged on the [wishlist](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403508516352539/).

So, you'll have to wrap the request, in Python :

```py
import requests
query = 'My String'
r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%s&type=page' % query)
result = r.json
result['data'] = [ item for item in result['data']
                   if query.lower() in item['name'].lower() ]
print [ item['name'] for item in result['data'] ]
```

Now you only have exact matches.

Answer (score -1):

try using Unicode, U+0200 is the space bar, so concatenate "My", U+0200, and "String".  No clue if that works.