# Irrelevant results in graph search api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that there is some bugs reported to Facebook about this subject, but I'll ask here too.

This call:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sebrae&type=post

Returns a lots of results that doesn't have the keyword "sebrae" for example.

Is there something that we can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do exact searches on the Facebook Graph. The best option is to filter the results yourself. See this related question for more detail:

[Using the Facebook Graph API to search for an exact string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547023/using-the-facebook-graph-api-to-search-for-an-exact-string)

Comment: Yes, we are already doing this.

The problem is that the real results, that we know that exists, doesn't appear in the return of the calls, just the wrong results.